# Referencing entity inside aggregate by local ID

Tags: domain-driven-design

How do you properly reference an entity inside an aggregate? For example, by the index of a list (doesn't seem smart if you re-order the list); a GUID (thought it was supposed to be local?); or some other incrementing counter?

For example:

```
class Cart
{
  public IReadOnlyList<Item> Items => _items.ToList();

  public AddItem(Item item)
  {
  }

  public RemoveItem(/* Item or ItemId or index (int)? */) <- Here
  {
    _items.Remove(xxxxx); // <- And here
  }

  private readonly List<Item> _items = new List<Item>(); // Maybe need different data structure
}

class Item
{
  // Local identity here? 

  public int Quantity { get; private set; }

  public Item(Product product)
  {
    // use product properties needed
  }

  // other item properties
}
```

It seems wrong for a client to have to return an `List<Item>` from the `Cart` to then use the index to remove the Item. Additionally, if I instantiate the Item outside the class prior to adding it, how do I impose a local Id (I would have a GUID if instantiating outside)?

TL;DR how to deal with local identities of entities (i.e. how local is "local")?

Comment: You should use a `GUID` to reference a nested entity.

Comment: DDD doesn't enforce a specific format for internal IDs, only that one should not reference a mutable nested-entity outside the Aggregate.l

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A client does not add or remove an `Item` to/from `Cart`. A client commands the `Cart` to add/remove `Product` (VO) and `quantity`. It’s only an `Item` once it is in the `Cart`. Does that make sense? Allowing a client to hold a reference to an `Item` could potentially break invariants should it modify the `Item` from outside the `Cart` aggregate.

In terms of how the `Cart` keeps track of each `Item`, this is up to you. Don’t overthink it. Focus on the behavior you would like to achieve and let the data that enables it be an implementation detail. It’s really not important how the inner workings of your `Cart` are organized. If you want to use a GUID or counter, just do it. Don’t worry about what “seems” right. Maybe you don't even need a `List<Item>`. There are other ways of organizing the data.

I know that’s probably not what you want to hear, but offering a specific solution would mean bringing the focus of this discussion on the data of your system instead of its behavior. That’s not the DDD way.

Comment: if Product is a VO wouldn't this imply that it would not hold a SKU since that's a form of identity?

Comment: The term "Value Object" does not mean an object has no identity, rather, that it's identity *is* the aggregate of it's values such that two objects are the same if their values are equal (e.g. an `EmailAddress`). Maybe a `Product` only has a single `SKU` property? I have no clue. You are passing `Product` to `Item` in your example. For the same reason you don't want to let a client have a reference to an `Item`, you don't want them to hold a reference to `Product` either (or make it a VO). Maybe the signature to add an `Item` to your `Cart` looks like `Cart.Add( string sku, int quantity )`.

Comment: @king-side-slide your thinking makes a lot of sense, but supposing Product lives in another Bounded Context (say, Catalog), where would you make the transition? I'm still learning, but I'd say not to make Cart (BC1) accept a Product (BC2) because that would cause a hard coupling between these two BCs. Then accepting a CartItem into Cart also makes sense because CartItem would be the representation of a Product in the Cart's BC. What do you suggest?

Comment: @king-side-slide I just realized the answer to my question above lies in your previous comment: maybe passing the product SKU or something like that. Please disregard the question.